# slack user invitation to workspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slack, slack-api

while trying to send invitation to users on slack, i am going though error. i hope i get idea from here. here goes my code:

```
SLACK_INVITE_URL = 'https://example.slack.com/api/users.admin.invite'

def perform(email)
  uri = URI.parse SLACK_INVITE_URL
  response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {
    email: email,
    channels: 'C02G8J689',
    token: ENV['token']
  })
  json_response = JSON.parse response.body
  json_response
  rescue => e
    error = e
  end
end
```

I am going through this error:

```
{"ok"=>false,
 "error"=>"missing_scope",
 "needed"=>"client",
 "provided"=>"identify,bot,incoming-webhook,channels:read,groups:read,users:read,usergroups:read,channels:write,chat:write:user,chat:write:bot,usergroups:write"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are Missing the `client` Scope.

You haven't added the `client` scope which Slack is telling you in the error.

The client scope "Receives all events from a workspace in realtime" which the users.admin.invite

You can read about it here https://api.slack.com/scopes/client and about users.admin.invite https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md

Comment: And you will need a legacy token to get the client scope. Normal tokens do not have it.

Comment: I have added scope but now i am having response as {"ok"=>false, "error"=>"no_perms"}. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have used normal token. So that you are facing the problem like this. Your problem must be solved if you use legacy token instead of the normal token.

Comment: I have used legacy token generated from this link https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens, problem stil exists